# PHP and two-directional text searching

Tags: php, regex, text-search

Given a text file with many strings.

If, for example, do a search for **red apples**, the following code:

```
$search = "red apples";
$contents = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$pattern = "/^.*$search*\$/m";
preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches);
implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```

will return (along with other strings) the following one:

```
Plate with many red apples blah blah
```

I need to found the same string, but with searching for **apples red**. Are there any ways to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: reverse the words in search string and search again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search_inversed = implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', $search)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<?php

$string = 'Lets locate red apple, or even, apple red!';

$search = 'red apple';

$search_parts = ( strpos( ' ', $search ) !== false ) ? explode( ' ', $search ) : array( $search );

preg_match_all( '#(' . preg_quote(  implode( ' ', $search_parts ), '#' ) . ')|(' . preg_quote( implode( ' ', array_reverse( $search_parts ) ), '#' ) . ')#i', $string, $matches );

echo '<pre>' ;
print_r( $matches[0] );
echo '</pre>' ; 

?>
```

Notice the use of strpos() and preg_quote() usage in order to avoid regex pattern errors.